# Convert excel file from XLSX to XLSB in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, smartxls

I am using Java + Apache POI to generate an excel file (format xlsx/xls). Due to huge data the generated excel file (format xlsx/xls) takes more size (~50 MB).

So I am trying to convert xlsx/xls to xlsb to reduce the size of the excel file.

Here is the problem: Apache POI does not support writing to xlsb file. So what I am trying is:

1. Generate a xlsx/xls file using Apache POI.
2. After that convert generated xlsx/xls to xlsb. For this I am using
   SmartXls Java library. But this library is not open source. You need to
   buy license for this. Also I checked EasyXls Java library, but it also requires buying a license.

Below code is used to convert xlsx/xls to xlsb using SmartXls Java library:

```
WorkBook wb = new WorkBook();
wb.readXLSX(.../xlsxPath);
wb.writeXLSB(new java.io.FileOutputStream(.../xlsbPath));
wb.dispose();
```

Kindly someone help me whether any open source library is available for it or is there any other way to do this conversion in Java.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally `.xlsx` is pretty similar sizes to `.xlsb` files, what makes you think you'd get any noticable savings?

Comment: No. xlsx and xlsb has some different in terms of size, loading and closing. Ex: If xlsx size is 10 MB, after convert to xlsb the size reduced to ~4-5 MB. Try to save xlsx file to xlsb using Excel application. You can see the difference.

Comment: Hi, Is any one know how to do that?

Comment: There isn't any free Excel library that knows xlsb file format. Even for money, there are only a few.